# Duda con un método de una clase en Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, clase, class, javascript-metodo

Muy buenas, estoy aprendiendo a programar en JavaScript y también con Typescript y tengo un reto que hacer, se trata de lo siguiente:
Tengo una clase hecha que trata de un libro, en esta clase tengo un método el cual debería devolverme toda la información del libro la cual es el título, su número de páginas y el autor, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?
Actualmente mi código es

```
class Libro{
    private titulo: string;
    private numeroPaginas: number;
    private autor: string;

    constructor(titulo:string, numeroPaginas:number, autor: string){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.numeroPaginas = numeroPaginas;
        this.autor = autor;

    public mostrarInfo():string{
        let informacion:string;
        for(informacion in this)
    {
        

    return informacion;
        }
    }
}

    let primerLibro = new Libro("El Gran Stan", 152, "6245312-OWM9128", "Stanley O'Donnell", "Sony Books");
    primerLibro.mostrarInfo();
    console.log(primerLibro.mostrarInfo());
```

No consigo hacerlo funcionar, ¿qué debería hacer?

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas simplemente algo como `public mostrarInfo():string{return \`El título del libro es "${this.titulo}" y su autor es ${this.autor}. El libro tiene ${this.titulo} páginas.\`}`?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla.

Answer (score 1):

EL problema es que tienes tu método `mostrarInfo()` dentro del constructor.
Aquí dejo el código en *TypeScript* y su compilado a *JavaScript*

### TypeScript

```js
class Libro{
    private titulo: string;
    private numeroPaginas: number;
    private autor: string;

    constructor(titulo:string, numeroPaginas:number, autor: string, isbn:string,editorial:string){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.numeroPaginas = numeroPaginas;
        this.autor = autor;
    }
    public mostrarInfo():string{
        return `Titulo: ${this.titulo}\nPaginas: ${this.numeroPaginas}\n${this.autor}`;
    }
}

let primerLibro = new Libro("El Gran Stan", 152, "6245312-OWM9128", "Stanley O'Donnell", "Sony Books");
primerLibro.mostrarInfo();
console.log(primerLibro.mostrarInfo());
```

### JavaScript

```js
class Libro{
    constructor(titulo, numeroPaginas,ISBN,autor,editorial){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.numeroPaginas = numeroPaginas;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.ISNB = ISBN;
        this.edutorial = editorial;
    }
    mostrarInfo(){
        return `Titulo: ${this.titulo}\nPaginas: ${this.numeroPaginas}\n${this.autor}`;
   }
}

let primerLibro = new Libro("El Gran Stan", 152, "6245312-OWM9128", "Stanley O'Donnell", "Sony Books");
primerLibro.mostrarInfo();
console.log(primerLibro.mostrarInfo());
```

Comment: Si bien esto es una solución, recuerda usar la sintaxis de Typescript, ya que el OP utiliza este lenguaje, te sugiero editar tu respuesta y agregar lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por el comentario. Solo vi la etiqueta de `JavaScript` y también el titulo de la pagina dice `JavaScript`, no me detuve a ver que lo pedía para `TypeScript`